# Can we use repository pattern and Unit Of Work in ASP.Net WEB API.?

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm Developing ASP.Net Web Api. For developing WEB API,  Do I need Repository Pattern and Unit Of Work, what are the benefits they have and when can we use them ?
suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: your request is your unit of work.  You can certainly use the repository pattern is you choose.

Answer (score 6):

You can most definitely use the repository pattern in WEB API.You just need to do some research and find out the problem it's trying to solve and if it's the right fit for your application.Repository is a good choice when:

1. You have a lot of CRUD(Create Read Update Delete) functionality in your application that needs to be performed on different entities(SQL tables for example) and you want to centralize data access and make future additions of new entities easy as application evolves.
2. You want to have a substitution point for unit testing.
3. You want to apply a domain model to simplify business logic.
4. You want to implement and centralize a caching strategy for the datasource.

You can use repository pattern without unit of work. To check if you need UOW ask yourself this question - Does my application require transactional support?If yes, then implement a UOW, otherwise just use repository pattern.

Have a look at the links below, this helped me in the past to implement repository and unit of work patterns:

[Generic repository in C#](http://blog.falafel.com/implement-step-step-generic-repository-pattern-c/)

[CRUD operations using repository pattern and Unit Of Work](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte)